# How to map json array to java class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to map request body from postman to spring boot entity,

```
{
"college":"0",
"collegeName":"",
"email":"a.r@g.com",
"firstName":"Mike",
"gradEndYear":"2017",
"gradStartYear":"2014",
"lastName":"worrell",
"marks":[
    {"sem1":60},
    {"sem2":70},
    {"sem3":80},
    {"sem4":60},
    {"sem5":60},
    {"sem6":60},
    {"sem7":70},
    {"sem8":60}
    ]
}
```

the problem is I tried to map the marks array to map but I am getting the following error

> message": "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY
>   token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2b05836e; line: 9,
>   column: 9] (through reference chain:
>   icms.external.springboot.candidateRegistration.model.CandidateRegistrationForm[\"marks\"])

Java model

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class CandidateRegistrationForm
{
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String college;
    private String collegeName;
    private String gradStartYear;
    private String gradEndYear;

    private Map<String, Integer> marks = new HashMap<>();

//getters and setters
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you change your json so that it can be mapped to a java map data structure, in that case the json will be like 
`"marks":
{
"sem1":60,
"sem2":70,
}`

Or use an arraylist instead of the map.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is represented by JSON object, not an array. Thus you should change your json:

```
{
"college":"0",
"collegeName":"",
"email":"a.r@g.com",
"firstName":"Mike",
"gradEndYear":"2017",
"gradStartYear":"2014",
"lastName":"worrell",
"marks":[
    {"sem1":60},
    {"sem2":70},
    {"sem3":80},
    {"sem4":60},
    {"sem5":60},
    {"sem6":60},
    {"sem7":70},
    {"sem8":60}
    ]
}
```

into

```
{
"college":"0",
"collegeName":"",
"email":"a.r@g.com",
"firstName":"Mike",
"gradEndYear":"2017",
"gradStartYear":"2014",
"lastName":"worrell",
"marks":{
    {"sem1":60},
    {"sem2":70},
    {"sem3":80},
    {"sem4":60},
    {"sem5":60},
    {"sem6":60},
    {"sem7":70},
    {"sem8":60}
    }
}
```

This is how `Map` is represented in JSON. If you want to keep this JSON, change your class to:

```
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String college;
private String collegeName;
private String gradStartYear;
private String gradEndYear;
private List<Map<String, Integer>> marks = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();
```

Then you can easily flatMap it:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream()
                                .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                         Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                         Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class CandidateRegistrationForm
{
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String college;
    private String collegeName;
    private String gradStartYear;
    private String gradEndYear;
    private List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> marks = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>>();

//getters and setters
  }
```

marks should be list of json objects i mean `map<String, Integer>` can be viewed as `{"sem1": 60}` and `list<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>>` will be `[{"sem1":60}]`.